# "SassError: The target selector was not found" when using SCSS Modules and Bootstrap in Next.js

Tags: css, sass, next.js, bootstrap-5

I am using Next.js with SCSS Modules. I installed `boostrap` with `npm install bootstrap`. I then created a file called `common.scss` inside `/public/scss/`. I have the following contents in this file:

```css
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid';
```

When I try to create a class like this:

```css
@import '../../public/scss/common.scss';
.footer {
  @extend .container-fluid;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[4]!./styles/components/Footer.module.scss
SassError: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .container-fluid !optional" to avoid this error.
  ╷
4 │   @extend .container-fluid;
  │   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  styles/components/Footer.module.scss 4:3  root stylesheet
```

Is there something else I need to do or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: did you fixed this problem? @davidaap

Comment: Sadly no, the only solution I found was to apply bootstrap classes directly on JSX and combine them with my custom SCSS using the `classname` npm package.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this problem in my project. And I has solved by:

I `@import` the `scss` file in `vite.config` by [css.preprocessorOptions](https://vitejs.dev/config/#css-preprocessoroptions), I found that when I re-`@import` in single `.vue` file, the error happens. for the reason is, the duplication of imports of the `.scss` file.

Hope it works for you.